# Pass the destination URL of clicked link to javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

After reading [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575957/jquery-get-url-from-click-and-pass-to-confirm-button-in-dialog) I was able to pass the URL of a specific div to jQuery upon clicking the link. However, I have multiple links of the page and I want to pass their individual href values to jQuery upon clicking. Right now the code selects all links on the page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".view-frontpage a").click(function (event) {
    href = $('.view-frontpage a').attr('href');
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(href);
   });
});
```

The result of this currently is that it pops up a dialog displaying the href property of the first link on the page, regardless of which link is clicked. How do I change this to give me the href of the link that has just been clicked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work.  Change:

```
href = $('.view-frontpage a').attr('href');
```

To:

```
href = $(this).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

First, it's a good idea to use [event](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) [delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/)  so you don't actually create a handler for every link on your page.

In your case, jQuery binds `this` inside your click handler to the click event target (the element that's been clicked on), so you need to do `href = $(this).attr('href');` to get the href of the link you need.

Here is the full code using the new jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function (available since 1.7)

```
$(document).on('click', '.view-frontpage a', function(e) {
    alert($(this).attr('href'));

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});​​​
```